# Create a pandas dataframe from dictionary whilst maintaining order of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

When creating a dataframe as below (instructions from [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/basics-data-analysis-python-pandas-tutorial/)), the order of the columns changes from "Day, Visitors, Bounce Rate" to "Bounce Rate, Day, Visitors"

```
import pandas as pd

web_stats = {'Day':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
             'Visitors':[43,34,65,56,29,76],
             'Bounce Rate':[65,67,78,65,45,52]}

df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)
```

Gives:

```
Bounce Rate  Day  Visitors

0  65           1    43      
1  67           2    34      
2  78           3    65      
3  65           4    56      
4  45           5    29      
5  52           6    76
```

How can the order be kept in tact? (i.e. Day, Visitors, Bounce Rate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to use `columns`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

web_stats = {'Day':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
             'Visitors':[43,34,65,56,29,76],
             'Bounce Rate':[65,67,78,65,45,52]}

df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats, columns = ['Day', 'Visitors', 'Bounce Rate'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Day  Visitors  Bounce Rate
0    1        43           65
1    2        34           67
2    3        65           78
3    4        56           65
4    5        29           45
5    6        76           52
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are not considered to be ordered in Python <3.7.

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

web_stats = OrderedDict([('Day', [1,2,3,4,5,6]),
                         ('Visitors', [43,34,65,56,29,76]),
                         ('Bounce Rate', [65,67,78,65,45,52])])

df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write the column names which becomes really inconvenient if you have multiple keys you may use

```
df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats, columns = web_stats.keys())
```